# Oozie HUE dashboard is not displaying the graph

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

As my Title says, oozie workflow dashboard is not displaying the graph on the UI. With the research, I found a lot of questions, [JIRAS](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-5419) and the questions in [horton works portal](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/88934/oozie-cant-display-the-graph-cause-number-of-actio.html), which really didn't help me.

I'm creating the job.properties and workflow.xml from the command line and submitting the job from the command line, doing through UI is not my option.

Below is the sample workflow.XML I'm running

```
<workflow-app
    xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='Workflow_Name' xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2">
    <global>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </global>
    <start to="firstFork"/>

    <fork name="firstFork">
        <path start="Job1"/>
        <path start="Job2"/>
        <path start="Job3"/>
        <path start="Job4"/>
        <path start="Job5"/>
    </fork>
    <action name="Job1" retry-max="2" retry-interval="10">
        <shell
            xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
            <exec>SCRIPT.sh</exec>
            <file>${Path}/SCRIPT.sh#SCRIPT.sh</file>
            <file>${configFile}</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="firstJoining"/>
        <error to="EMAIL"/>
```

Thank in advance !!

Comment: You should specify which version of Hue you have... It was apparently fixed in 4.0, and 4.1 is the latest

Comment: How do I get the version, without being as admin ?

Comment: Ask an admin? The front dashboard page should say "Welcome to Hue X.YZ"

Comment: Cloudera CDH is still on Hue 3.9 according to https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cm_vd_cdh_package_tarball_513.html

Comment: But maybe it's Hue 4 if it looks like this https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/08/new-in-cloudera-enterprise-5-12-hue-4-interface-and-query-assistant/ Although Cloudera could just port the UI forward, not necessarily any other patches

Comment: You are right, this is because of the older version.. thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

The JIRA you linked to is closed as a duplicate. According to [Hue-6144](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-6144) it's resolved in Hue 4.0

If you're using CDH, it may be difficult to know which patches are included in your Hue installation, but the interface for Hue 4.0 is only available in CDH 5.12 despite the packaging information saying its 3.9+patches

If you have access to the Hue server, the best you could do to find the issue is probably to compare the Python / JS changes in that JIRA & PR to your installation

I've not tried inspecting my workflows via my Hue installation, so I can't say if it's actually resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Oozie workflow using XML then graph will not be appear. If you want graph then you should create it with the workflow editor.

Comment: Creating workflow through editor is not my option as I mentioned in the question @Manish Pansari

Comment: Then you will not be able to see it, as per my knowledge.

Comment: I am using Oozie 4.2 and still not able to see my work flow , which I have created using xml.